# Template definition outside class body:VC2010 vs GCC 4.9

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, arguments, definition

I can compile this code with GCC 4.9

```
struct Space2 {
  static const int Size = 2;
};

struct Space3 {
  static const int Size = 3;
};

template <typename Space>
struct A {
  void f(int a[Space::Size]); //error C2244
};

template <typename Space>
void A<Space>::f(int a[Space::Size]) {
}

int main() {
  typedef Space2 Space;
  int a[Space::Size];
  A<Space> m;
  m.f(a);
  return 0;
}
```

But I have an error with VC2010 compiler:

```
error C2244: 'A<Space>::f': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration  
main.cpp(11): see declaration of 'A<Space>::f' definition  
'void A<Space>::f(int [Space::Size])'     
existing declarations  
'void A<Space>::f(int [Space::Size])'
```

Why?

P.S. When I put definition of `f` into `A`, this code was compiled fine both with GCC4.9 and VC2010.

Comment: Appears like a bug in MSVC.

Comment: Works fine in VS2013.  Avoid getting stuck on old tool versions, lots of changes in C++ these days.

Comment: It also "works" correctly if you remove the dimension sizing from the parameter decls (which are useless anyway with array to pointer conversion). It does, however, still puke with `int (&a)[Space::Size]`, which somewhat surprised me.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631554/error-c2244-on-templated-member-variable-with-templated-argument-function-only